# Setting DialogResult only after ShowDialog() in WPF

Tags: wpf, dialog

I have a window that I sometimes open using `Show()` and sometimes using `ShowDialog()`. In the second case, the returned dialog result is important for me. But if I set the `DialogResult` after calling `Show()` I get an `InvalidOperationException`. Is there a way to find out which method was used to open the window and set or not the `DialogResult` accordingly? Or is there another way?

Of course I know I can catch and ignore the exception, but I don't like this solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use  [System.Windows.Interop.ComponentDispatcher.IsThreadModal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.componentdispatcher.isthreadmodal.aspx) inside the window to determine if it runs on a modal thread or not.

Comment: Doesn't always work, in our case we had to wrap the DialogResult = x; call in a try/catch for proper behavior.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at set_DialogResult in Reflector, it checks _showingAsDialog to determine whether the dialog is modal. Unfortunately this is a private field.

Do you always construct a new instance of the window before calling Show()/ShowDialog(). If so, you could pass an argument to the constructor indicating how it is to be shown.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Form.Modal` property to check the kind of usage.

In the case of using `Form.Show()` you have to use another way to let the caller know of any results of the Form.

Is there a reason to use both ways of showing the form?

Comment: That property doesn't exist in WPF

Answer (score 0):

How about just setting this.DialogResult = DialogResult.blah in the form closing event?

Comment: How would that help? That would still set it even after Show() and cause the exception.
BTW I use WPF (I didn't specify that clearly) so the DialogResult is bool?.

Comment: before I do this.Close(); in the Modal Window I set this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; and in the main Form this is exactly what I get. Thank you sgrassie :)